# If three events are pairwise independent, are they independent "collectively"?

Tags: probability, independence

Three events $A, B, C$ satisfy:

$P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$

$P(B \cap C) = P(B) \cdot P(C)$

$P(A \cap C) = P(A) \cdot P(C)$.

Does this imply $P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A) \cdot P(B) \cdot P(C)$?

How to prove that it's true or not?

Comment: It is not true in general. See the (counter-)example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_independence

Comment: This answer can be found here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1606205/543867